# Jquery to validate the e-mail on my form on keypress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

My contact form has an email textfield that requires validation. I have used `onblur="alert(/([A-Z0-9a-z_-][^@])+?@[^$#<>?]+?\.[\w]{2,4}/.test(this.value))"` but it seems not to work onkeypress.

Comment: You are using `onblur` then how can it work on key press? Use `onkeypress`

Comment: no it wont.  I mean I need something that will work onkeypress.

Comment: See it work http://jsfiddle.net/d6w3zt4y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keypress` event. Try with this -

```
onkeypress="alert(/([A-Z0-9a-z_-][^@])+?@[^$#<>?]+?\.[\w]{2,4}/.test(this.value))"
```

I would prefer to use `onblur` in this case.

You can also use jquery -

**HTML**

```
<input id="email_address">
<span id="error" style="display:none;color:red;">Wrong email</span>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#email_address').on('keypress', function() {
    var re = /([A-Z0-9a-z_-][^@])+?@[^$#<>?]+?\.[\w]{2,4}/.test(this.value);
    if(!re) {
        $('#error').show();
    } else {
        $('#error').hide();
    }
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4mmazvgv/)

Comment: I used this and as soon as I type any word in the textfield,  a 'false' alert pops up and does that continously as i type

Comment: Check the use of jquery. Hope it would solve the issue.

Comment: @TheSalt check the demo also.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
   <input type="text" class="keyup-email text-input" name="7" value="">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.keyup-email').keyup(function() {
    $('span.error-keyup-7').remove();
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if(!emailReg.test(inputVal)) {
        $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-7">Invalid Email Format.</span>');
    }
});
    });
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/091ep28h/3/

Answer (score 1):

What about,

```
onkeypress="alert(/([A-Z0-9a-z_-][^@])+?@[^$#<>?]+?\.[\w]{2,4}/.test(this.value))"
```

and in jquery for element,

```
<input type="text" id="email" />
```

try,

```
$('#email').on('keypress',function(e){
     //if(e.which == 13){ // if you want it on enter keypress
     // read more on https://api.jquery.com/event.which/
     alert(/([A-Z0-9a-z_-][^@])+?@[^$#<>?]+?\.[\w]{2,4}/.test(this.value));            
     //}
});
```

One more thing I would suggest here in case of validation, you need to recheck your validation on submit of your form because one can click your submit button directly in that case your `email field` will not be focused then your added events(`onblur` and `onkeypress`) will get never fired.

You should use [keyup event](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) like

```
$('#email').on('keyup',function(e){
     if(e.which == 13){ // check email on enter keypress
         alert(/([A-Z0-9a-z_-][^@])+?@[^$#<>?]+?\.[\w]{2,4}/.test(this.value));            
     }
});
```

```js
$('#email').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) { // check email on enter keypress
    alert(/([A-Z0-9a-z_-][^@])+?@[^$#<>?]+?\.[\w]{2,4}/.test(this.value));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Email:
<input type="text" id="email" />
```

Comment: I used this and as soon as I type any word in the textfield,  a 'false' alert pops up and does that continously as I type.

Comment: It is because everytime you hits any key it will check for a valid email anf hence return false(for invalid emails). You can try it with `enter keypress` and use keyup event, try my updated answer.